# Как отформатировать числа в метках на оси X в Chart?

Tags: c#, winforms

История такая, есть график, отображающий точечным графиком данные которые парсятся из файлика excel.
Эти данные нужно нормально отобразить, решил делать в Chart. Как изменить тип данных чисел которые находятся под осью, или хотя бы сбросить несколько чисел после запятой. [image: Ось Y - отобразилась нормально, ось X - нет]

```
partial class Plot : Form
{
    List<List<PointOfData>> SortedArray = new List<List<PointOfData>>();
    List<string> Strings = new List<string>();
    TeachMaterial teachMaterial;
    List<List<double>> dataX;
    List<List<double>> dataY;
    List<string> ArrayOfClass;
    public Plot(TeachMaterial teachMaterial)
    {
        dataX = new List<List<double>>();
        dataY = new List<List<double>>();
        ArrayOfClass = new List<string>();

        this.teachMaterial = teachMaterial;
        InitializeComponent();
        
       SortedData();
        List<Series> series = new List<Series>();
        for (int k = 0; k < Strings.Count; k++)
        {
            // create a series for each line
            //Series series1 = new Series(ArrayOfClass[i]);
            series.Add(new Series(Strings[k]));
            double[][] arr = FormingDataForVis(SortedArray[k]);
            series[k].Points.DataBindXY(arr[0], arr[1]);
            series[k].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
            series[k].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
            series[k].MarkerSize = 10 ;
        }

        chart1.Series.Clear();
        foreach (var item in series)
        {
            chart1.Series.Add(item);
        }

        // additional styling
        chart1.ResetAutoValues();
        chart1.Titles.Clear();
        chart1.Titles.Add($"Scatter Plot (N0 points per series)");
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Horizontal Axis Label";
        var i = chart1.ChartAreas[0].Axes;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Vertical Axis Label";
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGray;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGray;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [форматирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) через свойство `LabelStyle.Format`.

Вот так:

```cs
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "0.00";
```

Или вот так:

```cs
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "{0:0.00}";
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло.